# Using url to set value in shiny app without input element

Tags: shiny

I'd like to make a shiny app that pulls a value from the url, but doesn't need to have an input element to work. E.g. I know I could do:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput("text", "Text", ""),
    textOutput("outtext")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$outtext <- renderText(input$text)
    observe({
      query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
      if (!is.null(query[['text']])) {
        updateTextInput(session, "text", value = query[['text']])
      }
    })
  }
)
```

and that would pull from the app's url after /?text=abc, but what I'd really like is to be able to print the value from the url without having a textInput box. Is this possible?

Comment: Have a look at `reactivePoll`

Comment: Thanks @HubertL - that looks like a nice idea though probably overkill for what I need, but really good to keep in my back pocket for the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; render the query parameter directly:

```r
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textOutput("outtext")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$outtext <- renderText(getQueryString()[["text"]])
  }
)
```